# dell latitude rugged

Tags: dell

Good day Ubuntu community, I'm a Master of Law, currently studying Data Science, after a Bachelor in Business Informatics. I am not that new to coding and my new field of studies requires me to switch to Linux for obvious reasons, the problem is i have nave used anything other than Windows and I have a very rare laptop- Dell Latitute 5420 Rugged. There are close to no topics on the internet about such a laptop using Linux, so I'm unsure if it will be good or will i have too many ports and features not working on Linux, for example it has LED keyboard, supports 2 batteries, has Fingerprint sensors and Face recognition, Touchscreen display etc. Can someone help me decide if I should do it and whether those things will keep working after switching to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop is [certified for Ubuntu 18.04](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201906-27175).

This means that Dell officially supports it with Ubuntu, but you may need specific drivers (that you can likely obtain from Dell support) or a specific kernel (see kernel reference in the certification report). From the listing the touchscreen seems to be included in the certification, but not the fingerprint reader. Status of the face recognition is debatable.